# Confusion regarding momentum and energy

Tags: homework-and-exercises

Can a body have momentum without energy? 
Please don't use a lot of differentiation.
A little theoretical background in the answer would be appreciated.

Comment: If a body has momentum, it is moving. If it is moving it has kinetic energy. It also has potential energy and rest energy but I am guessing you are not interested in those. A very good site for these questions is www.physicsclassroom.com and the equations involved are easily understood there. The equations will tell you the difference between them, so please visit the site.That's pushing the boundary of answering homework questions, but you should look up Wikipedia, after reading the physics site above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it's not possible. Angular momentum is defined as cross product of radius vector and linear velocity. Angular momentum is only zero when the body doesn't possess any translatory or rotatory motion, in which energy can never be equal to zero